# Framerate live streaming webm with dash and ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, live, webm

I am streaming a live video with ffmpeg and dash.js using
 [these instructions.](http://wiki.webmproject.org/adaptive-streaming/instructions-to-do-webm-live-streaming-via-dash) It works well except that the video is playing at a too high framerate. No framerate is specified in the manifest.
Creating the Chunks:

```
SET VP9_LIVE_PARAMS=-speed 6 -threads 8 -static-thresh 0 -max-intra-rate 300 -deadline realtime -lag-in-frames 0 -error-resilient 1
ffmpeg -re -r 25 -i tcp://localhost:8891 ^
-map 0:0 ^
  -pix_fmt yuv420p ^
  -c:v libvpx-vp9 ^
    -s 800x600 -keyint_min 25 -g 25 %VP9_LIVE_PARAMS% ^
    -f webm_chunk ^
    -header "webm_live/glass_360.hdr" ^
    -chunk_start_index 1 ^
  webm_live\glass_360_%%d.chk ^
```

Creating the Manifest:

```
ffmpeg ^
  -f webm_dash_manifest -live 1 ^
   -r 25 ^
  -i webm_live/glass_360.hdr ^
  -c copy ^
  -map 0 ^
  -r 25 ^
  -framerate 25 ^
  -f webm_dash_manifest -live 1 ^
    -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=0" ^
    -chunk_start_index 1 ^
    -chunk_duration_ms 1000 ^
    -time_shift_buffer_depth 7200 ^
    -minimum_update_period 7200 ^
  webm_live/glass_live_manifest.mpd
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MPD
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011"
  xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011"
  type="dynamic"
  minBufferTime="PT1S"
  profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011"
  availabilityStartTime="2016-03-30T13:02:53Z"
  timeShiftBufferDepth="PT7200S"
  minimumUpdatePeriod="PT7200S">
<Period id="0" start="PT0S" >
<AdaptationSet id="0" mimeType="video/webm" codecs="vp9" bitstreamSwitching="true" subsegmentAlignment="true" subsegmentStartsWithSAP="1">
<ContentComponent id="1" type="video"/>
<SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" duration="1000" media="glass_$RepresentationID$_$Number$.chk" startNumber="1" initialization="glass_$RepresentationID$.hdr"/>
<Representation id="360" bandwidth="1000000" width="800" height="600" codecs="vp9" mimeType="video/webm" startsWithSAP="1"></Representation>
</AdaptationSet>
</Period>
</MPD>
```

Any Ideas how to fix this?

Comment: did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/730) you should write

```
-use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1
```

for the input stream.